# C# Regex.Split and Regular expression

Tags: c#, guid

I have string, I need split it two times and select part which goes after special character.

Lets say:

```
string myString = "Word 2010|82e146e7-bc85-4bd4-a691-23d55c686f4b;#Videos|55140947-00d0-4d75-9b5c-00d8d5ab8436";

string[] guids = Regex.Split(myString,";#");
```

So here I am getting array of two elements with Value + GUID. But I need only Guids, like:

> [0]82e146e7-bc85-4bd4-a691-23d55c686f4b
>
> [1]55140947-00d0-4d75-9b5c-00d8d5ab8436

Any way of doing it in one/two lines?

Comment: One thing worth mentioning here is that using `Regex.Split` (in the context you have above) rather than `String.Split` is pointless (and I would suspect has more overhead). And personally I'd just have two functions, one that splits as you have above and the other that then splits on the pipe.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this but just because you *can* do it in one line doesn't mean you *should* (readability comes into play if you get too fancy here).  There's obviously no validation here at all.

```
string myString = "Word 2010|82e146e7-bc85-4bd4-a691-23d55c686f4b;#Videos|55140947-00d0-4d75-9b5c-00d8d5ab8436";

string[] guids = Regex.Split(myString, ";#")
                      .SelectMany(s => Regex.Split(s, @"\|").Skip(1))
                      .ToArray();

Assert.AreEqual(2, guids.Length);
Assert.AreEqual("82e146e7-bc85-4bd4-a691-23d55c686f4b", guids[0]);
Assert.AreEqual("55140947-00d0-4d75-9b5c-00d8d5ab8436", guids[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could easily do this without a regex if the last part of each is always a guid:

```
string[] guids = String.Split(";").Select(c => c.Substring(c.Length - 36)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] guids = myString.Split(';').Select(x => x.Split('|')[1]).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string myString = "Word 2010|82e146e7-bc85-4bd4-a691-23d55c686f4b;#Videos|55140947-00d0-4d75-9b5c-00d8d5ab8436";

//split the string by ";#"
string[] results = myString.Split(new string[] { ";#" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

//remove the "value|" part
results[0] = results[0].Substring(results[0].IndexOf('|') + 1);
results[1] = results[1].Substring(results[1].IndexOf('|') + 1);

//Same as above, but in a for loop. usefull if there are more then 2 guids to find
//for(int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
//  results[i] = results[i].Substring(results[i].IndexOf('|') + 1);

foreach(string result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var guids = Regex
    .Matches(myString, @"HEX{8}-HEX{4}-HEX{4}-HEX{4}-HEX{12}".Replace("HEX", "[A-Fa-f0-9]"))
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```